# SyntaxError when pasting multiple lines in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble copy-pasting code in Python. Say I have the following code I want to paste into a Python interpreter:

```
string_one = "Help"
string_two = "Me"
```

Locally, running 3.8.5 on a Mac OSX 10.15.7, if I paste that code, I get `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`.

However, if I ssh into another machine, open up Python (3.7.4), and paste those two lines, I get no error. Also, when I paste those two lines into a Python 2.7.16 shell, I get no error. What could possibly be the problem here?

Python 3 (problem shell)
[image]

Python 2 (non-problem shell)
[image]

Comment: It will be something to do with line feeds.

Comment: I have no problem pasting multiple lines of input into the Python REPL on a Mac.

Comment: End-of-line characters. Your Python 3 treats it as a single line.

Comment: @PM77-1 The problem happens with any code I paste into the interpreter. Did something change regarding EOL in 3.8.5 or is there a way I can address this?

Comment: Where do you copy this code from? What happens when you paste this code into Notepad-like editor?

Comment: You could open a triple quoted string in the interpreter `text = '''` then do the paste, then add the closing `'''`. Now `repr(text)` will show you what characters you got. Also, where did you copy it from?

Comment: @tdelaney I get `'\'string_one = "Help"\\nstring_two = "Me"\''` from that

Comment: @IainShelvington - why wouldn't it be worth a question? Python interpreter seems crazy... this seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @tdelaney the Python interpreter is not "crazy" it executes whatever you pass to it, the OP is pasting code with line ending issues and it doesn't help anyone that finds this question as it's user error

Comment: Oops, should have said `print(repr(text))` - you got the repr of the repr... had me confused there.

Comment: @IainShelvington - then how do you explain that pasting to a triple quoted string works? Or that other versions of python work? To say that this "needs more focus" is a real head scratcher.

Comment: @tdelaney pasting into a triple quoted string is completely useless, it doesn't do anything other than prove that text can be pasted. No-one has been able to replicate the issue, therefore it's user error and is of no use to anyone

Comment: @IainShelvington I know how to copy and paste. It is clearly not just user-error, there is a problem here. It just that it presents itself vaguely.

Comment: @IainShelvington - Opposite. I asked for the test to see if there was a paste problem. What remains is that the parser came to the end of a statement but found extra text. That the display did a newline but the interpreter didn't inject ">>>" or "..." are both interesting. Just because we can't reproduce here doesn't mean there isn't a problem that other Mac OSX 10 users might find.

Comment: @pete - The error is E_BADSINGLE in parsetok.c in the cpython source. If you grab it from github make sure you roll back to 3.8.5 before looking because parsing has changed in 3.9. But it isn't easy code to follow. Unfortunately, I can't come up with an explanation for this.

Comment: @pete - this occurred for me running python (didn't matter which python version- I tried several) in an interactive shell on MacOSX after an iTerm update. To fix... In iTerm: Preferences>Profiles>Terminal>"Terminal may enable paste bracketing". Once I unchecked that to disable paste bracketing, I was back to normal. Don't know if you're in Iterm, but I had the same symptoms- broken on my local mac, but fine on remote linux servers. Investigate paste bracketing in your terminal and you may resolve. BTW, not a useless question.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I was having this issue, and the solution in the question helped me.

Comment: @ChriZuidema I rolled back your edit; if you would like to submit that solution as a proper answer, I'll delete the community wiki answer I added with that content.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there is a bug in readline (which is used by Homebrew to install python)

Short answer:

```
echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Long answer:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193

---

(This was erroneously edited into the question; I have rolled back that edit, and am pasting the solution as an actual answer instead, and tagging as Community Wiki.)