# Pasting multiple lines in MacOs Python shell returns SyntaxError

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I had to reinstall my MacBook.
I downloaded python from brew.

When I copy and paste code in the python shell from brew, the text is highlighted and the code not executed.

When I use the stock python from my MacBook there is no problem.

Please check this short video:
https://youtu.be/CrTzBpVdcVM

I'm not the only one with this problem, however no solutions had been found yet:

[SyntaxError when pasting multiple lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637242/syntaxerror-when-pasting-multiple-lines-in-python)

https://python-forum.io/Thread-How-to-paste-several-lines-of-codes-to-the-Python-console

https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/428

Comment: I dont know how to solve this, but maybe try using ipython? you can install it with `pip install ipython`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in readline (which is used by Homebrew to install Python)

Short answer:

```sh
echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Long answer:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193